# Unwinding from Storyboard prevents Delegate from being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, segue

I have a UIViewController several segues deep that when the use is finished, should `unwind` and take them back to the DashboardViewController.

I created the `unwindToDashboard` method in the Dashboard and hooked a button up to the `Exit` in my `FinishViewController`. So that when its clicked will fire the unwind action.

That works fine.

But I need to pass back data to the Dashboard from the FinishViewController.

So I created a delegate `ProcessDataDelegate` for the `FinishViewController` and made the Dashboard conform to it.

However, the delegate method in the Dashboard is **NOT** called.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

**DashboardViewController.m**

```
#import "FinishViewController.h"

@interface DashboardViewController () <ProcessDataDelegate>{
    FinishViewController *fm;
}
@end

@implementation DashboardViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(!fm){
        fm = [[FinishViewController alloc] init];

    }

    fm.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)unwindToDashboard:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {
//empty
}

#pragma mark PROTOCOL METHODS

-(void) didFinishWithResults:(NSDictionary*) dictionary{
    NSLog(@"Dashboard method called didFinishWithResults");
}

@end
```

**FinishViewController.h**

```
@class FinishViewController;
@protocol ProcessDataDelegate <NSObject>
    @required
    - (void) didFinishWithResults: (NSDictionary*)dictionary;
@end

@interface FinishViewController : UIViewController 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ProcessDataDelegate>  delegate;
@end
```

**FinishViewController.m**

```
@interface FinishViewController () 
@end

@implementation FinishViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"fired via the button to the exit--- Segue: %@", [segue identifier]);
    [delegate didFinishWithResults:nil ];
}

@end
```

Comment: If you are using segues and storyboard you can't instanciate a viewController with [[ alloc]init] you need to get your destination view controller in prepare for segue method and pass the delegate there

Comment: What if the required segue is 4 or 5 segues in? That's why I am using the unwind feature.

Comment: But only one go to finishViewController don't you?, and have an identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass your delegate in `prepareForSegue` method of your `DashboardViewController`, there get the `destinationViewController` and cast to `FinishViewController` if the identifier is equal to your expected segue identifier

**Something like this**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"fired via the button to the exit--- Segue: %@", [segue identifier]);
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"])
    {
         ((FinishViewController*)[segue destinationViewController]).delegate = self
    }
}
```